# RibbonBar with Windows7 look and feel?

Tags: windows, ribbon

Do you know any ribbon with windows 7 look and feel?

Answer (score 1):

The [Windows SDK v7.0](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=a91dc12a-fc94-4027-b67e-46bab7c5226c&DisplayLang=en) has support for the "Scenic" Ribbon: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ScenicRibbon. There is a C++ sample [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=141e13e8-b10b-4356-aaa5-609b2981574a&displaylang=en).

The latest version of BGCSoft ControlBarPro also supports the same style: http://www.bcgsoft.com/featuretour/tour256.htm

Answer (score 1):

The [WPF Ribbon Preview](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Wiki/View.aspx?title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview) has the Windows 7 look and feel by default.